If Astro.js fetch failed - discard component
Lets say I have very simple Astro component which is fetching some data.
const data = await fetch("path-to-data.json").then((response) => response.json());
data.map(item => <h2>{item.title}</h2>)

If my data fetching failed I have error:
Failed to parse URL from path-to-data.json

I would like just to skip this "component", if data fetch failed, not to break entire site.
How to do that? (Not with React, not Vue.. just Astro.js)
Thank you

You can chain .catch(() => null) to the fetch call which will make data be null if there's any error.
Then, in the template, render the contents only if data is present.
---
const data = await fetch("path-to-data.json").then((response) => response.json()).catch(() => null)
---

{data ? data.map(item => <h2>{item.title}</h2>) : null}


This seems to be working! Thank you!

@Gnesh don't forget to accept this as the answer if it solved your problem
